# Laravel- Auto Change Currency based on Country

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an ecommerce website, using Laravel and mysql. I need to auto change the currency based on the client country.
I already have the selection based currency change. I need to auto change the currency to the one of the user's country when visiting the website.

Comment: You cannot do this automagically, since user can be using a proxy or just because some countries ose more than one currency: you could go for the most used one in the second case, but best way would be to let user choose which currency use and save this in their preferences if user is also registered.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

We have a laravel package called [`Torann/laravel-geoip`](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip) for this purpose.

Add below snippet after finished installing this lib;

```
$geoData = geoip(request()->ip());
$currency = $geoData['currency'];
```

For more details, see this link; https://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/doc/